# Uploading video to Youtube from PHP driven webpage

Tags: php

It is possible to upload a video file from my own webpage on you tube without using google. If yes how to do it?

Comment: Since Google owns YouTube no, it's not...

Comment: This question makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

You need google if you are going to search for an answer. Yes you can do it without google too. (you can us bing or yahoo) ;-)

but you need You tube API account.

Here is a [sample php article about using Youtube API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-youtubeapi/), [another one](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html)